# cv::goodFeaturesToTrack gives the corner vector size as zero

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying opencv `cv::goodFeaturesToTrack` to get the corner points. I did the following code.  But the output corner vector size is always zero but the Corners capacity is changed.

```
using namespace cv;

void main()
{
    Mat img = imread("cameraman.tif",CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

    std::vector<Point2f> Corners;

    cv::goodFeaturesToTrack(img,Corners,10,0.01,10);

    std::cout<<Corners.size()<<endl;
}
```

The Output is 0

Comment: I assume that your parameters may not be the best for this image. The `cameraman` image does not have so many good corners. The update in the capacity comes from the first parameter (10) in the function call (the max number of corners).

Can you try with another image and lower the last parameter to 1 or 2 ?

Comment: @sansuiso I tried by changing the image and also the parameter to 2 and 1. But it resumes as it is. No change.